# Crontab unable to run cron job every 1 minute Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, cron, forever

I have Ubuntu running on EC2 and I have written this script to check if my site is up or not.

Here is my `serv.sh` file:

```
#!/bin/bash
# My first script
yourURL="http://mywebsite.com"


if curl --output /dev/null --silent --head --fail "$yourURL"
then

    echo "At $(date) => Success 200 OK" >> log/log.txt
else
    forever restartall
    echo "At $(date) => Failed, restarted now" >> log/log.txt
fi
```

I am trying to run this script every 1 min on crontab but the log file does not update means the cron is not executing, why?

Here is my cron tab: `crontab -e`, I want to run my script every 1 minute.

```
* * * * * /home/ubuntu/cron/serv.sh
```

But this is not working, I tried this too:

```
 0,1 * * * * /home/ubuntu/cron/serv.sh
```

None of these are working.

Comment: What makes you think it's not working?  Does it work when you run it manually?  Also, the relative paths you use for the log are not a great idea in crontabs.  Better to use the full path or have the script explicitly cd into the directory you expect to be in.

Comment: yes it works when i run manually by doing ./serv.sh

Comment: You still haven't said why you think it's not running.  Have you checked /var/log/system.log?

Comment: Yes I have checked /var/log/syslog it says May 29 08:20:01 ip-172-31-28-35 CRON[19656]: (ubuntu) CMD (/home/ubuntu/cron/serv.sh)
May 29 08:20:01 ip-172-31-28-35 CRON[19655]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)

Comment: @KarenB is the job running or not ? I am trying to output the result of my script file in log/log.txt as u can see in my code. But the log.txt updates only when I run the cron manually, the log.txt file never updates when the cron runs itself in background. this is causing me to believe that cron is not running :(

Comment: In my first comment (maybe you missed the edit), I pointed out that using relative paths in the cron script isn't a good idea, because crond doesn't run from /home/ubuntu.  Change log/log.txt to /home/ubuntu/log/log.txt and see what happens.

Comment: Check [debugging crontab](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info). Did you give execution byte to the script? Is cron itself running? test with `* * * * * echo "hello" >> /tmp/hello`. What if you replace the cronjob with `* * * * * /bin/bash /home/ubuntu/cron/serv.sh`.

Comment: @KarenB Now the log files are being written every one minute but forever restartall is still not working, why ?